# Embed audio stream from CDN

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to embed a police radio stream from broadcastify into my web application. I have tried using the  tag with no success (code below). Any suggestions?

```
 <audio src="https://broadcastify.cdnstream1.com/28286">Davenport</audio>
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with that embed... just tested it.  Can't reproduce your problem.  Check your developer tools... they might have blocked your origin.

Comment: yeah nothing show up on my page... Do I need to add some type of styling?

Comment: Audio elements don't have a UI unless you enable it... one second, will write an answer for you.

Comment: Also, hello from Moline.  Stay safe over there!

Comment: crazy! Was just bored and decided to make a little app to chat about the current craziness... url is infecting.xyz [ignore the messages lol]

Comment: Hey brad, just figured it out by using the controls and autoplay options! Thanks for the help and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the audio element, you need to add the `controls` property.

```
<audio src="https://broadcastify.cdnstream1.com/28286" controls>Davenport</audio>
```